# Getting Version Number Error Using RealImages

Tags: r, image-processing

I am new to looking at .jpg images in R, when I try to load the RealImages library, I am getting the error:

```
install.packages("ReadImages")
library("ReadImages")

mypic <- read.jpeg('my_pic.jpg')
plot(mypic)
```

> Warning in install.packages :
>     package ‘ReadImages’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)

What package can I use?

Comment: try to download from their github page using the `remotes` package of `devtools` then you should be able to use that package

Comment: In your question you have written `install.packages("ReadImage")` (I.e. you have missed an 's' off the end. Is this just a typo?